# On SelectionChanged update Label to value from XML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an XML file that looks like

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Name>Item 1</Name>
        <FirstProperty>42</FirstProperty>
        <SecondProperty>37</SecondProperty>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>Item 2</Name>
        <FirstProperty>11</FirstProperty>
        <SecondProperty>35</SecondProperty>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

and a XAML file that looks like

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="ItemsXml" XPath="Items/Item" Source="Items.xml"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox Name="itemList" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsXml}, XPath=//Name}"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="80,0" Width="30"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="80,50" Width="30"/>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Content="{Binding ElementName=areaList, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,50" Content="Bind me?"/>
</Grid>
```

This shows a `ListBox` containing two elements, `Item 1` and `Item 2`, and two rows containing a `TextBox` and a `Label` each. Is it possible to bind the `Label.Content` properties to respectively `FirstProperty` and `SecondProperty` of the selected item in the `ListBox`? The above code binds one `Label` to the *value* of the selected item, which works correctly except that's not the value I want to display. I'd guess what I really need is to specify a source of `itemList` and find the matching value with XPath, but firstly I'm not sure how to do that comparison and secondly I'm curious to know if there's a better way, assuming there is one at all.

If this isn't possible the only solution I can think of is to do it programmatically in the `SelectionChanged` event handler. That would work but I'd rather not have to split up the behaviour like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this shoud do the trick,

Bind the `Items` directly to the `ListBox` and use `DisplayMemberpath` to show the property you want from the `Item` node.

Then by setting the `Label` `DataContext` to the `ListBox` `SelectedItem` node you can access all properties via `XPath` in the `Label` `Content`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="ItemsXml" XPath="Items/Item" Source="Items.xml" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox Name="itemList" Width="172" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsXml}}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="0,0,570,0" />

    <Label DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=itemList}" 
           Content="{Binding XPath=FirstProperty}" Width="160" Height="30" Margin="178,48,403,233" />

    <Label DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=itemList}" 
           Content="{Binding XPath=SecondProperty}" Width="160" Height="30" Margin="178,12,403,269" />
</Grid>
```